# How long should i excercise?

Tags: running, exercise, workout-routines, bodyweight-exercises

I used to do physical activity in my school-days but after college it got reduced and after that none. I started doing exercises five month back I am following this regular exercise routine.

1. 6km running (30 min)
2. 20 jumps touching my chest from my knees
3. 15 push ups
4. Lie down and touch my nose with my knee 10 times
5. Duck walk and jump for some 5m forward and backward.
6. Finally some stretching,

Total time taken is approximately  45 min. My weight is 58Kg.

It's intense for me and I sweat a lot, and I don't know if I am overdoing it.

Can I add some more exercises to my daily routine or should I just change the exercises each day to new ones. I want to do some plank exercises too.

Also, does it requires me to take more protein since I am doing this stuff.

Comment: To me this routine looks a bit strange. What are your goals?

Comment: I Dont know about making any routine.If you could help me that would me great.I would like have have really strong core so i am thinking of doing plank excercise.

Comment: How often do you do this routine?

Comment: i do this 6 days a week

Comment: it depends what you mean by "core".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Workout length (45mins-1h)

A successful workout  shouldn't really exceed more than an hour to *an hour and a half*. 45 minutes is great, your body can push 100% throughout that time. Anything more and you start to slack off or give less intensity on the other exercises.

### Workouts > 1 hour 30 mins

Personally, my trainings go from an hour and a half to two hours (stretching and abs included). Although, I eat very well and provide enough carbohydrates so that I don't feel drained. I drink intra-workout shakes (which provide BCAAs, Carbs, etc) to help me stay hydrated.

### Adding exercises

What you can do is switch up your exercises, try something new. You need to perform things your body is not used to - that way it will adapt and change accordingly. If things get easier, yes you can definately add in some more exercises;  like 15-30 burpees or plank exercises.

**Stronger Core**

If your goal is a stronger core, here are some intense abdonimal exercises I perform and suggest to my more advance clients:

1. [10 v-crunches](http://www.ibodz.com/files/exerciseimages/v-crunch-1.JPG) (legs elevated off the ground slightly)
2. [10 single-leg v-crunches](http://www.ibodz.com/files/exerciseimages/v-crunch-with-single-leg-1.JPG) (legs elevated off the ground slightly)
3. [30 seconds with legs and upper body slightly elevated](http://cdn.vogue.com.au/media/article-steps/4/3/3/0/43333-1_asl.jpg) (lift arms if possible)
4. [20 crunches](http://www.flattenbelly.com/elements/exercise_images/basiccrunch.jpg)
5. [15 bicycle crunches](http://popworkouts.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/bicycle-crunches-exercise2.jpg)
6. 1 minute plank

### Protein intake

As for the protein, yes your body should intake more protein than the usual person. You're excerting more energy and your muscles need to rebuild. Protein will help you do that. You should take about 1.5g of protein pour kilogram of bodyweight. Knowing that you're 58 kilos, you should take approximately 87 grams of protein per day.

Keep in mind, do not take all the protein at once or else you will just poop it out. Separate it throughout the day for more successful results. Your meals also have protein so try to balance it out with protein shakes if needed.

Comment: "A successful workout shouldn't really exceed more than an hour to an hour and a half." -- I find this subjective.  "Anything more and you start to slack off or give less intensity on the other exercises."  -- This also seems subjective.  Olympic weightlifters sometimes have 8 hour training sessions, same with a lot of sports.  Furthermore, what makes a workout "successful"?  This answer seems speculative.

Answer (score 2):

It totally depends on your goals. If you want to tone down, however in your case it doesn't seem to be what you are after or  If you want to get bulky like have muscles(biceps, triceps)  and abs then 1 Hr is the right time. You need to balance your diet and exercise accordingly. You need to take good and perfect amounts of Carbs, Calories, Proteins and Water every day. 15 Push Ups a day is a little less if you have been exercising since 5 months. Always keep going ahead while exercising slowly. Like every week add 10 more to what you do now. I would also suggest that you do some ab crunches. If you find swimming interesting, try doing that as well, it is a great way to stay in shape. 
Sweating is a good thing but remember to drink lots of water every day but not immediately before or after exercises. Yes, you may need more proteins but if you eat chicken or fish on a regular basis you might not require a protein shake everyday. However you must have one protein shake at least once in 3 days and if your exercise is rigorous then have 1 everyday.